# InfoPath form: How to redirect to the previous page after pressing on the submit button?

Tags: 2010, infopath, sharepoint-online, office-365

I am using SharePoint 2010 Online (Office 365). I have created a form in InfoPath for an external list.

You see some fields and a submit button.

When I press on the submit button everything is working fine (a new list item is created), but the page is not going automatically to the previous page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a user to another page by adding `&Source=http://somewhere.com` to the end of the URL that opens up the form.

Reference Link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/d83e7c6e-f01f-42c9-94fd-20ca78db27d8

Answer (score 2):

By Default when you are on a view and you create new or edit an existing form item you will be returned to the same view you were on to start with.

Example:

Starting on "My View"

Create New Form Item > Save

Returns to "My View"

The way to change this is to add the Source parameter to the URL before users enter the form.

Add `?source=<URL>` to the end of your address. In the example below I used the 'new form' page of my list. Also a side note if there are ever multiple url parameters the first one starts with a "?" mark and the rest are separated with "&". Example: urlwhatever.aspx?parameter1&parameter2&parameter3

Example:
https://sharepointURL/list/newform.aspx?source=http://sharepointURL/list/MyView.aspx

or:
https://sharepointURL/list/newifs.aspx?source=http://sharepointURL/list/MyView.aspx