# Return to last page visited

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-online, breadcrumb

I have Sharepoint in Office 365. The site is set like this:

Home>Training>Training Request Form.

I have it set so that, on submit, the Training Request Form displays a thank you and a link that takes people back to Home.

What the bosses want is that, on submitting the Request Form, the user is either redirected back to that particular Training, or given a link to take them back to that particular Training.

This one Form is the ending point of about 20 different Trainings (ex. Trainings A, B, C and D all link to this one request form) so I don't want to have to make separate Forms for each Training.

Is there a way to remember where the user accessed the Form from, and provide them with a way to return to that same page?

Comment: On submit is a custom function you wrote?

Comment: Yes, I made a rule in InfoPath. It switches to a custom "Thank You" view on submission.

Answer (score 0):

While opening the Training Request Form you should form the URL as follows

```
http://site/form.aspx?SOURCE=trainingURL
```

On submit you will get automatically get redirected to trainingURL

[Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70397/infopath-form-how-to-redirect-to-the-previous-page-after-pressing-on-the-submit)

[Javascript Solution](http://mnaveenkumar.blogspot.com/2012/04/redirect-infopath-webpart-to-custom-url.html)

Comment: So then instead of switching to a custom view, I should set the form to "close this Form on Submit" instead?

Comment: Yes. I haven't tested this, but give it a go

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working for me. I tried keeping the form open and closing it. I also tried putting the Javascript (with some adjustments) into the script Editor. No luck. Thanks though!